# Point zero on an elliptic curve

Tags: java, elliptic-curve

I am working on a library that allows me to work with elliptic curves. It is still at embryonic state, and so far it only consists of two classes, **EllipticCurve** and **Point**.

Right now I'm implementing the basic operations of existence, belonging, sum, reflection, etc.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck now that I have to implement the concept of zero, i.e., the point of the elliptic curve E crossing the line through P and -P, where P = (x,y) and -P = (x,-y). So, my question could be rephrased as "how do I implement a point at infinity?"

Here's part of the **Point** class so far:

```
public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
    private static final BigDecimal MINUSONE = new BigDecimal(-1);

    private BigDecimal x;
    private BigDecimal y;
    private EllipticCurve e;

    public Point(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y, EllipticCurve e) {
        if(x != null && y != null && e != null) {
            if(liesOn(x,y,e)) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.e = e;
            }
        }
    }

    public Point reflect() {
        return new Point(x,y.multiply(MINUSONE),e);
    }

    public Point add(Point o) {
        if(this.e == o.getE()) {
            if(this == o) {
                return this.multiply(2);
            }
            if(o == this.reflect()) {
                return /*THE INFAMOUS ZERO POINT*/;
            }

            BigDecimal a;
            BigDecimal b;

            /*
             * computation I still haven't implemented
             */

            return new Point(a,b,e);
        }
    }
    /*
     * other methods
     */
}
```

P.S.: I am aware of the existence of java.security.spec.EllipticCurve, but since I'm going to use this class mostly for mathematical purposes, I felt the need to create my personal library *ex novo*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to represent infinity per se using `BigDecimal`. The only way in Java I know is:

```
Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
```

or `Integer`, `Float` etc. You also can't take `valueOf` from the above, since it will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

You can use a workaround, i. e. a very large value that you know will always be larger than any other.

Comment: I had that thought through my mind, but I am using BigDecimals instead of Double because I will probably have to handle some huge numbers.

Comment: Yep, I see the problem. Well, like I said, to my best knowledge, you simply can't implement infinity in BigDecimal. This is Java however, so performance is not that critical, I think defining some `static` value replacing infinity will not hurt you in any way (but keep in mind, this it rather against good programming practice, and other users will probably diss me for it ;) ).